# Iterate through ViewGroup children using RxJava

Tags: android, android-layout, rx-java, rx-android

I'm new to RxJava.

I have founded this solution for iterating through each child of `ViewGroup`:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_layout);
for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
    View child = layout.getChildAt(i);
    child.setEnabled(false);
}
```

but I had trouble converting it to RxJava.

Can someone please give me a hint with description?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the use of RxJava

Comment: can u plz describe more?

Comment: Do you have a reason for iterating using RxJava?

Comment: @GVillani82 It's cleaner and I can manage it in different threads and all

Comment: Hopping to another thread for iterating a List will not help you improve performance. I would suggest to use RxJava if you have latency or you have to combine streams of events over time, but please don't collect Arrays with it.

Comment: @HansWurst Are you trying to say that it is better to use the "for loop" for the sake of performance e.g this situation?

Comment: You should use only the UI thread for operating on the UI. As @HansWurst pointed out, you should use RxJava if you need to create a stream of events, and combining them for more complex operations. Using RxJava for iterating over a list is, IMHO, abusing.

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do. If you want to collect the items to a collection and then do some latency stuff, collecting the collection would make sense, but not on another thread. The overhead of switching to another thread or even init a new thread and wait for the os to schedule your work on the new thread and back then to the ui thread to mutate state of the viewelements is not recommended. As in premature optimisation is note recommended either.

Comment: @HansWurst  that was very helpful thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

alright, as I read the [Reactive Documentaion](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/range.html) I found `range` operator,
the answer I came up with is look like this,

```
       Observable.range(0, layout.getChildCount())
            .map(layout::getChildAt)
            .subscribe(child -> child.setEnabled(false));
```

Comment: This will result in an exception, because `Integer` cannot be casted to `ViewGroup`.